# Filtering a table based on multiple criteria where an items attributes are entered as separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a SQL Server table design as detailed below. The table is called `Info`.

I need to understand the SQL statement required to return the correct results for the following two examples.

```
Id  | ItemId | FieldName | Value
 1  | 302    | Colour    | Red
 2  | 303    | Length    | 100
 3  | 304    | Length    | 25
 4  | 305    | Colour    | Blue
 5  | 306    | Colour    | Blue
 6  | 306    | Length    | 100
 7  | 307    | Colour    | Blue
 8  | 307    | Length    | 35
 9  | 308    | Colour    | Red
 10 | 308    | Length    | 100
 11 | 309    | Colour    | Red
 12 | 309    | Length    | 45
 13 | 309    | Shape     | Square
 14 | 310    | Shape     | Round
```

Example 1: I need to find out which Items (ItemId) have a Colour of "Red" AND a Length of "100" from the "Info" table - which should be only, ItemId 308

My limited SQL knowledge has taken me down the path of

```
SELECT ItemId 
FROM Info 
WHERE (FieldName = 'Colour') 
  AND (Value = 'Red')
```

but this returns Items 302 and 308, the similar query of

```
SELECT ItemId 
FROM Info 
WHERE (FieldName = 'Length') 
  AND (Value = '100')
```

returns 303 and 308, when the correct output should just be ItemId 308

The scenario I have may also require the expansion of this query to include more than two fields being defined as in the following example:

Example 2: I need to find out which Items have a Colour of "Red" AND a Length of "45" AND are "Square" - which should be only ItemId 309

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: You could just toss the word `INTERSECT` between those two select queries and rerun. That will turn it into one big statement where only the intersection of the two queries will be returned (`308`). You can use the same logic for your second  request of: red, 45, square. Three SELECT statements with INTERSECT between them.

Comment: Do you always have exactly two requirements, or might you have more or less? Do you care if they have other proeprties such as `Shape`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get what you're asking. I use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to join for each parameter that you're searching against. Then at the top I use a `SELECT DISTINCT` to get the ItemId.

```
DECLARE @SearchColor nvarchar(50) = 'Red';
DECLARE @SearchLength nvarchar(50) = '100';

SELECT DISTINCT i.ItemId
FROM Info as i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Info as iColor
        ON iColor.ItemId = i.ItemId 
        AND iColor.FieldName = 'Colour'
        AND iColor.Value = @SearchColor
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Info as iLength
        ON iLength.ItemId = i.ItemId 
        AND iLength.FieldName = 'Length'
        AND iLength.Value = @SearchLength
WHERE iColor.Id IS NOT NULL
    AND iLength.Id IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: @SadlyFullStack thanks for catching the typo. I see the copy and paste issue you mention. I'll fix.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a classic *[Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) with Remainder* question.**

There are many solutions, but if you want to make this flexible and able to deal with differing numbers of proprties then you need to normalize your input. You can use a table variable, temp table or TVP for this.

One common and pretty performant solution is to join the input, group it up and check you have enough rows

```sql
DECLARE @input TABLE (FieldName nvarchar(100), Value nvarchar(100), PRIMARY KEY (FieldName, Value));
INSERT @input VALUES
('Colour', 'Red'),
('Length', '100');

SELECT i.ItemId 
FROM Info i
JOIN @input inp
  ON inp.FieldName = i.FieldName
 AND inp.Value = i.Value
GROUP BY
  i.ItemId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input);
```

Answer (score 0):

First example:

```
select    ItemId
from     (
          select   ItemId
                  ,case when value = 'Red' then 1 end                   as mrk
                  ,case when try_convert(int, value) = 100  then 1 end  as mrk2
          from     info
         ) info
group by  ItemId
having    max(mrk)  = 1
   and    max(mrk2) = 1
```

| ItemId |
| --- |
| 308 |

Second example:

```
select    ItemId
from     (
          select   ItemId
                  ,case when value = 'Red' then 1 end                  as mrk
                  ,case when try_convert(int, value) = 45  then 1 end  as mrk2
                  ,case when value = 'Square' then 1 end               as mrk3
          from     info
         ) info
group by  ItemId
having    max(mrk)  = 1
   and    max(mrk2) = 1
   and    max(mrk3) = 1
```

| ItemId |
| --- |
| 309 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/172O3SLq)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get both results in one query and keep all the info.

```
select   Id
        ,ItemId 
        ,FieldName  
        ,Value
from     (
          select   *
                  ,count(case when value = 'Red' then 1 when try_convert(int, value) = 100  then 1 end) over(partition by ItemId)                            as mrk 
                  ,count(case when value = 'Red' then 1 when try_convert(int, value) = 45 then 1 when value = 'Square' then 1 end) over(partition by ItemId) as mrk2 
          from     info
         ) info
where    mrk  = 2 
   or    mrk2 = 3
```

| Id | ItemId | FieldName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 308 | Colour | Red |
| 10 | 308 | Length | 100 |
| 11 | 309 | Colour | Red |
| 12 | 309 | Length | 45 |
| 13 | 309 | Shape | Square |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vw2DrB8B)

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/). [`Try_Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can pivot and simply retrieve the info.

```
select *
from
(
select ItemId, FieldName, Value
from   info
) info
pivot(max(Value) for FieldName in(Colour, Length, Shape)) p
where Colour = 'red' and Length = '100'
   or Colour = 'red' and Length = '45' and shape = 'square'
```

| ItemId | Colour | Length | Shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 308 | Red | 100 | null |
| 309 | Red | 45 | Square |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q3dXvRso)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemId 
FROM Info 
WHERE (FieldName = 'Colour' AND Value = 'Red')
AND (FieldName = 'Length' AND Value = 100)
```

Comment: It is rare to find a column that has two different values for _the same row_. It's even less likely to find two such columns.